# Why are the SVG Text elements too high?

Tags: svg

I noticed the the root coordinates for a text element are not at the top left corner like a rect element:

[image]

Is there a way to set it such that when a text element is at (0,0), it fits inside the parent element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you well, you can use this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline

A) Chromium browsers

```
svg {
  dominant-baseline: hanging;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e7vc4bqj/

B) Chromium and Firefox

```
.text {
  dominant-baseline: hanging;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3zskd148/

SVG text coordinates are used to define its left bottom corner by default: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor

Hope this help :)

Comment: Looks like it needs to be applied to `text` rather than `svg`.

Comment: It's supported in all Chromium browser but not yet directly to the svg tag in FF (coming soon), at least I'm glad that it pointed you to the right direction :) Could you please mark this answer as useful to help others in the future.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

> Why are the SVG Text elements too high?

The `x` and `y` coordinates of a `<text>` element specify the start of the **baseline** of the text.  This makes complete sense.  You wouldn't want it to be the top left of the first character - because it would then be a difficult job to get text of different sizes and styles to line up.

There is no global option in SVG that changes that behaviour.  However see below for alternatives)

> Is there a way to set it such that when a text element is at (0,0), it fits inside the parent element?

Normally you would just adjust the `y` coordinate based on the font size.

However there are a couple of alternatives you can use:

1. One is the `xxx-baseline` properties (as @gengns has pointed out), that can alter how the character glyphs are positioned relative to the baseline.  Note however, that those attributes are not entirely reliable, due to mixed browser support.  Plus they depend on the font containing the correct data tables. Not all fonts have those tables.
2. A better option IMO is to use the `dy` attribute.  This adds a relative offset to the text position.  Meaning the text is actually positioned at `(x, y + dy)`.  And it is supported by all browsers.

```html
<svg width="200" height="150">

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="150" fill="skyblue"/>

  <text x="0" y="0"
        font-size="25px" dy="1em">asd</text>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: I recommend you use language that is not nearly as condescending.

Comment: Not to mention that this statement is just plain wrong: `There is no option in SVG that tells the renderer to display the text below the start coordinates.`

Comment: @wheeler I had no intention of being condescending. Which part do you think is that way?  As to your second point, I will update that sentence to make my point more clear.

Comment: `This makes complete sense.` To whom?

Comment: `You wouldn't want it to be the top left of the first character`. First, that is precisely what I want. Second, who are you to tell me what I do and do not want?

Comment: I was using the generic "you", meaning people in general.  I was not specifically referring to you in particular.  If you are not a native English speaker, then I apologise for the confusion.

Comment: How do you know what "people in general" do or do not want? Once again, you're making an imposition and providing an opinion where it does not belong, not to mention you didn't even answer my first question. You answer is condescending and I'm asking you once again to remove the language.